# Convert a scala Seq of string to key value pair

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a array like [1,2]

I have created an udf which will do a specific operation.Below is the UDF

```
def addOne(elements: Seq[String]) = elements.map(element => ("id",s"a-$element","v","In"))
```

so the outputp is like 
`[["id","a-1","v","In"],["id","a-2","v","In"]]`

I want to convert it into key-value pairs

The final o/p should be something like

```
{

id:"a-1",

v:"In"

},
{

id:"a-2",

v:"In"

}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I was actually tryting to to a named_struct and also tried using case statement,but nothing seems to work

Comment: See [Zip elements with odd and even indices in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601611/zip-elements-with-odd-and-even-indices-in-a-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it

```
def addOne(elements: Seq[String]) = elements.map(element => (List("id",s"a-$element","v","Ind").grouped(2).collect { case List(k, v) => k -> v }.toMap))
```

Thanks all for your response.

Answer (score 1):

You can Try following approach

Ive added if condition to handle if the number of elements is not even
This approach will give you mutable map

```
val seq = Seq(1,"a",2,"b")

val itr = seq.iterator

val newMap: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Any,Any] = scala.collection.mutable.Map()

if(seq.size % 2 == 0) 

while(itr.hasNext) {

 newMap += (itr.next->itr.next)

}

println(newMap)
```

Other option to get the result in a immutable Map

```
 val seq = Seq(1,"a",2,"b")


def listToMap[T](xs: Seq[T]) =
  xs.grouped(2)
    .map{case List(a, b) => (a,b)}
    .toMap


val newMap = listToMap(seq)

println(newMap)
```

Comment: It Should work with the UDF I have provided.It is working differently

Comment: It Should work with the UDF I have provided.I actually had used your second methood after suggestion from someone else,but I need to make it work with the UDF

Comment: Yes I changed,but I did not change requirement.I just added a new output value.Requirement is still the same

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```scala
  val df = spark.sql(
      """
        |select elements from values (array('a-1', 'a-2')) T(elements)
      """.stripMargin)
    df.withColumn("p", expr("TRANSFORM(elements, x -> named_struct('id', x, 'v', 'In'))"))
      .withColumn("p_json", to_json($"p"))
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +----------+----------------------+---------------------------------------------+
      * |elements  |p                     |p_json                                       |
      * +----------+----------------------+---------------------------------------------+
      * |[a-1, a-2]|[[a-1, In], [a-2, In]]|[{"id":"a-1","v":"In"},{"id":"a-2","v":"In"}]|
      * +----------+----------------------+---------------------------------------------+
      */
```

Comment: I am using spark 2.3.This is related to same question I was asking today morning to you.I had to create a UDF can not use spark 2.4.Instead of Transform I created the UDF   " def addOne(elements: Seq[String]) = elements.map(element => ("id","CIS-$element","CISKey","Ind"))"  But now stuck with converting into key value pair